# how to protect/secure public/login forms from CSRF on a headless system?

Tags: security, csrf

In a site where frontend is fully decoupled from the backend, where the frontend is not rendered and basically is only HTML + JS, what could be used to prevent [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) attacks for any public form including the login form itself?

I was thinking on using [json tokens](http://jwt.io/), but that creates a "[chicken-egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg)" scenario, since I need to a token to secure the request, but for getting the token I need to authenticate.

I could check the [HTTP referer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) or either I am thinking on getting a token via API call to the Backend, but besides this what could it be used?

Any best practices on this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "the frontend is not rendered"?

Comment: I mean that is static content that is not parsed by any language, code  that could be hosted on a CDN, basically just the html/css/js that interact via API with the backend.

Comment: So no specific server-side dependencies.  got it, thanks.

Comment: See [this answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/59529/8340) and [this answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/85893/8340).

Comment: @SilverlightFox Something I don't get properly, when using 'double submit cookies.' even if the cookie is set via client (javascript) still been secure ?

Comment: @nbari your question is really important and interesting. How did you resolve this problem?

Comment: @VadymVL I haven't solve it/work on it, but if you find something useful please let me know.